# What does (simple) $j/cm^2$ represent AND how does this result $6.959j/cm^2$?

Tags: energy, waves, laser, wavelength, medical-physics

According to the image shown below, this specific Laser Hair Treatment device claims that it has a concentration of $6.959 j/cm^2$. So far by research I have found that it needs around **$6\mbox{ to }7 J/cm^2$ for better hair growth**. You can find a slight description of it [here](http://www.overmachogrande.com/index.php?/omg/site_pages/your_laser_device_isnt_wont_be_strong_enough/). However the specific product which has shown here also claims that it **uses $443$ $J$ of energy** per treatment which is **20 minutes** long, and **80 Laser emitters** with **$678\pm 8$ nm of wavelength** which covers an area of **582cm2 of the scalp** out of $720cm^2$ of total scalp area. Here is the image of the Laser Hair Treatment Device which shows its specifications.

[image: Here is the image of the Laser Hair Treatment Device which shows its specifications].

And here is the paragraph which they have mentioned its specifications and energy distribution.

> The key to treating hair loss is lasers, but all lasers are not created equal. We use specially developed, high efficiency lasers that allow us to deliver the maximum amount of light and cover $582 cm^2$ of the $720 cm^2$ total scalp area in the average human head.   We don't want to bore you with numbers, but with over $440$ Joules per treatment and an optimised wavelength of $678\pm 8$ nm, each of the $80$ lasers is precisely tailored for maximum hair growth.

You can find the entire description about this device, [here](http://www.theradome.com/index.php).

According to my memory and knowledge I tried my best to get the result of $6.969 J/cm^2$ or something closer to it using these data and I failed. These are my questions.

1. What is (simple) $j/cm^2$ which is indicated here as $6.959 j/cm^2$? And why is it shown as $j/cm^2$ instead of $J/cm^2$?
2. Even so, how do I get the result of $6.959$ ($J/cm^2$ or $j/cm^2$) or something closer to it using these given data, as this device manufactures claim?

Your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on Skeptics.SE

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion @BrandonEnright. As you have said I have now re-posted the question at [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/19170/laser-hair-treatment-device-what-does-simple-j-cm2-represent-in-energy-and-ho) but I will still keep this question posted here for any further help from someone.

Comment: **IMPORTANT UPDATE:** According to the new found facts after further research, we have found [this video which is made by this device's manufacturers and if you go to 1 minute and 57 seconds of it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WBKeeR6SY8&t=1m57s), in the table which the person there explains, the 4th item shows that this device's concentration as $105 J/cm^2$ which puts the **entire problem under confusion** as the manufacturers have shown double standards of their product which **if true** will make this entire question **invalid and useless**.

Comment: However I will still keep this posted here for anyone who could make a sensible explanation by any chance on these data and the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like they mean J/cm^2 doesn't it - but they may well just be pulling numbers out of the air.

To be electromagnetic flux is should be W/cm^2 - but it looks like a dosage is intended.

440J/treatment over 582cm^2 is 0.756J/cm^2 per treatment.

But that just means that the little "j" does not mean what we think it does.
AFAIK: there is no evidence that any kind of laser treatment is effective as a treatment for hair loss.

It's snake oil - it is a waste of time pondering what snake-oil salesmen mean when they spout figures.

Comment: Yes I'm starting to doubt it so as well. Because the first thing if it is really $J/cm^2$ what they have meant, it is a big mistake scientifically and even so like you've explained, it doesn't make sense how they have got $6.959 J/cm^2$ out of these data. Thank you for your answer. I would +1 your answer for sure but I lack the 15 reputation score to do so.